# combine regex patterns javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regex patterns

1) `re1 = /^[0-9\b]+$/` is for allowing only numbers in the input field

2) `re2 = /^(7|75|750)$/` is for allowing first 3 numbers of input field to be "750".

Now, I want to combine both the regex patterns where the input field should allow only 750 as first 3 numbers and remaining digits as numbers. I tried following,

```
const re3 = /^(7|75|750)|0-9\b]+$/
```

but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `/^(?:7|75|750)[0-9]*$/` but `/^7(?:50?)?[0-9]*$/` is better.

Comment: Try: /^(?:7|75|(?:750[0-9]*))$/ It only allows extra digits if the start is 750.

Comment: If trying to validate user input I suggest jQuery plugin like https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/^(?:7|75|750)[0-9]*$/
```

Or,

```
/^7(?:50?)?[0-9]*$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `7` - a `7` char
- `(?:50?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences (i.e. this is optional) of `5` followed with an optional `0`
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Well, if you need to match the backspace char, add `\b` into the class, `/^7(?:50?)?[0-9\b]*$/`.

Comment: I don't want 50 to be optional, input should start with 750

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /^750\d+$/

const tests = [7503944, 343399, 7445, 7503043434];

tests.forEach(el => console.log(el + ": " + regex.test(el)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only numbers to be allowed in the input field, then set the input field type as **number**. It will allow only numbers and you can give **re2** regex pattern to check for the first 3 numbers.

```js
function details() {
  const re2 = /^(7|75|750)$/;

  let data = document.getElementById('inputdata').value;
  if (data.match(re2)) {
    alert('Data Valid!')
  } else {
    alert('Data Invalid!')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="inputdata" value=""></input>
<input type="button" name="" value="Check" onclick="details()">
```

Only **e** character will be allowed when the type of input field is number because **[e](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/e-eulers-number.html)** is an irrational number. I hope it helps.